# Graph of curve defined by $3x^2+3y^2-2xy-2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Graph the curve on the $2D$ plane defined by $3x^2+3y^2-2xy-2=0$

Let $q(X)=3x^2+3y^2-2xy , X=(x,y)^T$. The matrix associate with q is $A=\begin{bmatrix}3&-1\\-1&3 \end{bmatrix}$. Since its symmetric,$\exists P$ orthogonal such that $P^TAP=Λ$.

By finding A's eigenvalues, we see that this matrix is similar to $Λ =\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&4 \end{bmatrix} $ which is the associate matrix of $q'(Z) = 2z_1^2+4z_2^2$, where $Z=PX$. That gives me the equation $2z_1^2+4z_2^2=2 \implies z_1^2+2z_2^2=1$, which is an ellipse.
The initial equation describes a rotated elliptic cylinder, while the ellipse is not rotated.

My question is, shouldn't the graph of the ellipse be a projection of the graph of the initial equation in the $2D$ plane?

Comment: Be careful with your terminology. The graph of the *function* $q$ is an elliptical cylinder. The initial *equation*, however, is an implicit equation of an ellipse. The connection is that the latter is a level curve of the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $z_1$-$z_2$ coordinate system is rotated relative to the original one. That’s kind of the point of diagonalizing $A$: to shift into a coordinate system in which the principal axes of the quadric—the eigenspaces of $A$—are the coordinate axes.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you solve your equation for $y$?
$$y_{1,2}=\frac{1}{3}x\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{3}x\right)^2-\frac{3x^2-2}{3}}$$

Comment: I'm learning quadratic forms, so I'm using that method.

Comment: ok you Can compare both results

Comment: Yeah, but this ellipse is tilted and the one I found is not. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: hm i Can not see what you have done